# Was the casting of Marlon Brando and Trevor Howard in Superman (1978) a reference to, or inspired by, Mutiny of the Bounty (1962)?

Tags: dc, behind-the-scenes, superman-1978

I just noticed that in the 1978 *[Superman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078346/)* film, Jor-El’s main antagonist on the planet Krypton—the Moliom who orders Jor-El not to create panic with his theory of the planet’s immanent destruction—was played by Trevor Howard.  Very little the key scene between Howard and Marlon Brando as Jor-El made it into the final theatrical version of the film, although it is now available as part of the three-hour extended cut.

This immediately made me wonder whether the casting of Brando and Howard in opposition was influenced by their previous roles in *[Mutiny on the Bounty](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056264/)* (1962).  Brando played Master’s Mate Fletcher Christian, leader of the mutiny against Howard’s Captain Bligh.  (Trevor’s performance as Bligh is generally well regarded, while Brando’s was less acclaimed, and his bizarre behavior during filming was widely reported and probably did permanent damage to his career.)

Is there any information about this casting choice that indicates that Richard Donner and the Salkinds were influenced by *Mutiny on the Bounty* in their casting choices?  Brando famously got astronomically more money than anyone else in *Superman*—for a relatively minor role.  Was Howard perhaps cast as 1st Elder because of his known performance as Brando’s antagonist?

Comment: Even without looking it up, I could have told you that they filmed it at Pinewood. In those days productions needed to have x many English actors in order to earn union recognition which would, in turn, earn them a juicy tax exemption status. It's the same reason Star Wars has a bunch of senior English actors in key (non-starring) roles.